# Get rows based off of first records values

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table that looks like this:

```
field_value      field_label        record_id        data_element        data_id
                    8-7-1966             8            immunization           163
  8-7-1966          1966-8-7            163           immunizDate            164
                                        163           immunizProvider        165
```

I need to grab all three of these records, dynamically. I can get the first record by doing:

```
SELECT 
    field_value, field_label, record_id, data_element, data_id 
FROM 
    substance_data 
WHERE 
record_id = 8
```

But I need to somehow grab the other two records, knowing that that their record_id will equal the data_id of the first record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    field_value, field_label, record_id, data_element, data_id 
FROM substance_data 
WHERE 
    record_id = 8 
OR  record_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT 
                      data_id 
                  FROM 
                      substance_data 
                  WHERE 
                      record_id = 8
                 )
```

Comment: I wonder whether it's possible to get the whole chain of records recursively with one SQL statement. I.e. get the record with `record_id=8`, and all records having a `record_id` equal to the `data_id` of any of the previously selectd records.

Comment: @petersohn: it is possible with a recursive CTE query. The bad news is that mysql does not have recursive CTEs.

Comment: This solution was absolutely perfect. If it's not too much trouble, is there a way to grab where it says record_id = 8, and keep that. For example, i'm pushing this to an array, and using the record_id as the storage indice, is there a way to grab the first records_id, and pass it up out of the sql query?